# Basic Authentication subdirectory in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

is it possible to members accessing to one folder via `http://user@pass:domain.com/folder/` and special role ? 
i used :

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

it redirect to login page , but i want if they want to download file in destination folder via software can download through  entering user and pass directly not through web form

Answer (score 1):

This only works with [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). If you are using Forms Authentication then authenticated users are tracked with cookies and you cannot use such url.

Comment: i should use virtual directory to accomplish this or it is possible  via web.config in sub directory ?

Comment: Here's how you could enable basic authentication in IIS: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication